# Laravel : How to upload Multiple image file in multiple database field?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multiple-file-upload

I want to upload multiple image files in  database ..
Here is the view part :

```
<input type="file" name="photo[]" >
<input type="file" name="photo[]" >
<input type="file" name="photo[]" >
```

And I want to store the path into different field in database..

controller code:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {


        $product = new Product();
        $product->name = $request->Input(['name']);
        $product->description = $request->Input(['description']);
    $files = Input::file('photo');
            $names = [];

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $names[] = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            }
                $imageName1 = time().'.'.$names[0];
                $imageName2 = time().'.'.$names[1];
                $imageName3 = time().'.'.$names[2];         
            $product->primary_image = $imageName1;
                    $file->move('images/', $imageName1);
            $product->optional_image_one = $imageName2;
                    $file->move('images/', $imageName2);
            $product->optional_image_two = $imageName3;
                    $file->move('images/', $imageName3);
        $product->price = $request->Input(['price']);
        $product->save();

        return Redirect::to('product');

    }
```

I got the following Error:

> ```
> FileException in UploadedFile.php line 235:
> The file "3.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.
> ```

Can anyone what's the error for assigning into object? or solution please ..

Comment: How did you first declare `$product` variable? Are you sure it's a model (ex: `$product = new Product`)?

Comment: yes I declared `$product = new Product();` I just share here part of the controller

Comment: Can you please post the whole controller? Edit: Or at least everything before the `$product->primary_image = $imageName1;` part